# jQuery select specific optgroup and remove options

Tags: jquery

How can i remove options of a specific `optgroup` of a `select`

What i've done so far is:

```
function(data)
{
    $('.'+id).each(function()
    {
        $(this).find('option').remove();
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {              
        $('<option>').text(value).appendTo('.'+id);
        });
    });

}
```

And the `select` is

```
<select id="testers" class="testers_team-${info.problemId}">
    <optgroup label="Current Assigned Tester">
        <option>I'll think about this later</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Testers" class="test_list">
        <c:forEach var="testers_per_team" items='${test.KwekKwek}'>
            <option>${testers_per_team}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I want to remove the options of the second `optgroup class="test_list"` and repopulate it, i succeed to add options but not in the specific `optgroup` i want to know how:

1. Select a specific optgroup with a select that hast multiple optgroup
2. Remove the options that currently added to that
3. Add new option to the optgroup that currently selected

The current script above is under an `Ajax` but it removes all the  option of the dropdown, so please help.

**Note:** The value of `testers_team-${info.problemId}` is the same class of the `select` i posted above

Comment: What is the value of "id in $('.'+id) ?

Comment: $('.'+id) is the class of the dropdown in the codes, in short it has same value as `class="testers_team-${info.problemId}"` in the `select` i posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're finding, emptying and appending to the select. Select the `optgroup` and work with that instead:

```
function (data) {
    $('.' + id).each(function () {
        var $optGroup = $(this).find('optgroup.test_list');
        $optGroup.empty();
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $('<option>').text(value).appendTo($optGroup);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm, can you explain the details to me before i accept your answer?

Comment: It is explained.... It finds, it emptys and then it appends the option elements...